# Using a global array inside a class

Tags: php, arrays, class, constructor, global

My aim is to retrieve some data from a global array which is defined in another PHP file. My code is running inside "database.php" file and the array I want to use is inside "config.php" file.

My code is as below:

**config.php**

```
$CONFIG = array();
// ...
$CONFIG["DATABASE"] = array();
$CONFIG["DATABASE"]["USERNAME"] = "user";
$CONFIG["DATABASE"]["PASSWORD"] = "pass";
$CONFIG["DATABASE"]["HOSTNAME"] = "127.0.0.1";
$CONFIG["DATABASE"]["DATABASE"] = "my_db";
// ...
```

**database.php**

```
require('config.php');

class Database
{
    protected   $m_Link;
    private     $m_User;
    private     $m_Pass;
    private     $m_Host;
    private     $m_Data;
    private     $m_bConnected;

    public function __construct()
    {
        global $CONFIG;
        $this->m_User = $CONFIG["DATABASE"}["USERNAME"]; // Line #16
        $this->m_Pass = $CONFIG["DATABASE"}["PASSWORD"];
        $this->m_Host = $CONFIG["DATABASE"}["HOSTNAME"];
        $this->m_Data = $CONFIG["DATABASE"}["DATABASE"];
        $this->m_bConnected = false;
        $this->Connect();
    }

    // ...
};
```

The error given is:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected
>   '}', expecting ']' in
>   C:...\database.php on line 16

I couldn't figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

Please help me fix this error.

(Note: PHP version is 5.3.0)

Comment: Why don't you pass `$CONFIG['DATABASE']` as an argument to your `Database` class constructor? `public function __construct($config) {` Then you don't need to global it.

Comment: I agree with Greg. The (real) issue is not the typo, but you resorting to Global State instead of using Dependency Injection. Pass in the config array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`["DATABASE"}` = `["DATABASE"]` on all 4 lines.

Answer (score 6):

You aren't pairing your brackets properly

```
$this->m_User = $CONFIG["DATABASE"}["USERNAME"]; 
----------------------------------^
```

Should be

```
$this->m_User = $CONFIG["DATABASE"]["USERNAME"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You have typo error on line 16 and 3 after that.

`["DATABASE"} = ["DATABASE"]` should be `["DATABASE"] = ["DATABASE"]