# Can't write values into a global PHP array from a class method

Tags: php, arrays, object

PHP is not my forte but I've tried some OO code in it today. All fine except that my $replyArray array at global level doesn't get written by the jumble() class method of my solSet object. The penultimate var_dump in my code shows an empty array. I've tried throwing around global keywords and that hasn't helped. Because I am explicitly passing this variable by reference to my newly instantiated class, shouldn't this be enough?
Thanks!
kk

```
<?php


//create a solution set for translation of incoming user login requests

$widhi = 600;
$tileDim = 25;
$randArray = array ("0","1","2","3","4","5");
$replyArray = array ();


//create 5 positions and ensure neither overlap or edge collision
class solSet
{
  var $pos1;
  var $pos2;
  var $pos3;
  var $pos4;
  var $pos5;
  var $pos6;


  public function jumble($wh,$ts,$arrShuf,$reply)
  {
    foreach($this as $key => $value)
    {
      $newX = rand (($ts/2),$wh - ($ts/2));
      $newY = rand (($ts/2),$wh - ($ts/2));
      $randNo = array_pop($arrShuf);
      $value = "" . $newX . "_" . $newY . "_" . $randNo;
      $this->$key = $value;
      //push coords onto an array for later ajax
      $pushElem = "" . $newX . "_" . $newY;
      $reply[] = $pushElem;
    }
  }

}


//scramble the random number array for later popping
shuffle($randArray);

//make a solution object
$aSolSet = new solSet;
$aSolSet->jumble($widhi,$tileDim,$randArray,$replyArray);

//store it in a session
session_start();
$_SESSION["solSet"] = $aSolSet;

echo var_dump($replyArray);
echo json_encode($aSolSet);

?>
```

This seems to relate:
[Using a global array inside a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6184061/using-a-global-array-inside-a-class)
But this is what I have done. Also the whole world and his dog are saying that the global keyword is "doing it wrong". What to do?

Comment: You're not actually *"explicitly passing this variable by reference"* - that would be `public function jumble($wh,$ts,$arrShuf,&$reply)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `jumble` method needs to take `$replyArray` by reference - by default, PHP functions operate by value, which means that they operate on a copy of the variable, rather than modifying it. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

Change

```
public function jumble($wh,$ts,$arrShuf,$reply)
```

to

```
public function jumble($wh,$ts,$arrShuf,&$reply)
```

The ampersand in front of the variable name means that the parameter is passed by reference.

Comment: Ticked because that was exactly the issue. I was assuming reference. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, instead of updating the global var from within the class (bad for re-use and portability) you can simply return your new shuffled array:

```
public function jumble($wh,$ts,$arrShuf)
{
  $reply = array();
  foreach($this as $key => $value)
    {
      $newX = rand (($ts/2),$wh - ($ts/2));
      $newY = rand (($ts/2),$wh - ($ts/2));
      $randNo = array_pop($arrShuf);
      $value = "" . $newX . "_" . $newY . "_" . $randNo;
      $this->$key = $value;

      //push coords onto an array for later ajax
      $pushElem = "" . $newX . "_" . $newY;
      $reply[] = $pushElem;
    }

  return $reply;
}
```

... and update your global `$replyArray` with the response:

```
//make a solution object
$aSolSet = new solSet;
$replyArray = $aSolSet->jumble($widhi,$tileDim,$randArray);
```

You don't even need to pass the `$reply` parameter into your method at all then (note, one less parameter) and everything is all nice and self-contained.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I will do. I've ticked the answer below though because that was an answer to why my code wasnt working rather than a rewrite. Your answer for me makes the most sense though. I was just being stubborn, this is more logical.

Comment: Fair enough - I put a comment to the same effect as iaiann's at about the same time. I also upvoted his answer as it matched exactly what you were asking for ... though, personally, I'd prefer this method to passing by reference ;)

Answer (score 0):

reference the global array in the function

```
 global $replyArray;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have been told that is naughty though!